# Error linking inherited constructor

Tags: java

I am just beginning to learn constructors and inheritance java, can i know what error is present in my code that i cant link `Coordinate2` ?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Coordinate {
     protected int x;
     protected int y;

     public Coordinate() {

     }

     public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
     }

     public int getX() {
         return x;
     }

     public void setX(int x) {
         this.x = x;
     }

     public int getY() {
         return y;
     }

     public void setY(int y) {
         this.y = y;
     }

 }

 class Coordinate2 extends Coordinate {

     public Coordinate2(int x, int y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
     }

     public float distance(Coordinate2 c) {
         float dist;
         dist = (float)
         Math.sqrt(Math.pow((c.getX() - this.x), 2) +
             Math.pow((c.getY() - this.y), 2)
         );
         return dist;
     }

 }

 class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Coordinate2 c1 = new Coordinate2();
         System.out.println("enter x point");

         c1.setX(input.nextInt());

         System.out.println("enter y point");

         c1.setY(input.nextInt());

         Coordinate2 c2 = new Coordinate2();
         System.out.println("enter x point");

         c2.setX(input.nextInt());

         System.out.println("enter y point");

         c2.setY(input.nextInt());
         System.out.printf("the value in c1 are(%d,%d)\n", c1.getX(), c1.getY());
         System.out.printf("the value in c2 are(%d,%d)\n", c2.getX(), c2.getY());
         System.out.printf("the value in c1 and c2 are %2f.\n", c1.distance(c2));
     }

 }
```

Comment: You didn't call `super(x, y)`, so what do you mean by "linking"?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Why do you believe the arguments for x and y for constructor `Coordinate2(int x,int y)` don't matter and can just use `new Coordinate2()` without any arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend from a base class you should call the constructor within the child constructor, And you have two cases:

**First**: parent class has a default constructor implementation (means constructor without any parameters) and in this case compiler will call it implicitly if you didn't call it

Example, in your Coordinate class:

```
public Coordinate(){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

The compiler will call it implicitly in your child class if you don't call it, like:

```
public Coordinate2(int x,int y){
    //Implicitly call
    //super();
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

**Second**: You don't have in your super class default constructor implementation and have a custom constructor (constructor has parameters), then the compiler will not call it implicitly if you didn't call it and you shoul call it explicitly, like:

```
public Coordinate2(int x,int y){
    super(x,y);
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you call a superclass constructor, however.